# Date prompt syntax change in Select Statement

Tags: date, select, teradata, prompt

SQL that does run on SQL assistant does not run in Teradata Studio Express. I have narrowed it down to the date syntax within the SELECT statement.  What is the proper syntax (in the SELECT Statement) to return the date entered by the user in the result set.  I have changed the prompt syntax to '?\FirstDayOfWeek'  within the conditions & that does function properly as a pop up for the user, however it does not allow the query to run when used in the select statement.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't want the single quotes around your parameter.  What do you mean it does not allow the query to run?

Comment: Studio defaults to ANSI mode / ANSIDATE standard format _yyyy-mm-dd_. SQLA defaults to Teradata mode and site-defined date format.

Comment: for prompt, use the "where datecol=?" expression.

Comment: In this context different things can be tricky. To nail the root cause down, it would help to know the DDL of the column where the Parameter "FirstDayOfWeek" is used + the concrete ErrorMessage.

Without these infos the guesses above are the usual suspects (TMODE and correct DateFormat).